# Java datetimeformatter dropping minutes

Tags: java, datetime-format

So just as the title states my code is just throwing out the minutes part of any input time. Can't find any common questions so I'm making one. Code below

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("\nDeparture time (HH:MM): ");
        String timeText = scanner.next();
           LocalTime time= LocalTime.parse(timeText, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:MM"));
           System.out.print(time);
    }

}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong it would be grateful.

Comment: At a quick guess MM might be for month, try "mm" instead.  Read the docs to be sure.

Comment: Your very first port of call should ALWAYS be the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), a few second of reading will tell that `M/L month-of-year number/text 7; 07; Jul; July; J` and what you probably want is `m minute-of-hour number 30` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/4216767#4216767)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `mm` instead of `MM`

```
LocalTime time= LocalTime.parse(timeText, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
```

The complete formatting style for `DateTimeFormatter` is as below.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

MM - Month

mm - Minutes

Comment: Thank you, I dont know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Provide input as 
11:30
04:30
if provide 4:30 then it will throw error while parsing

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
public class dateTime {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nDeparture time (HH:MM): ");
    String timeText = scanner.next();
       LocalTime time= LocalTime.parse(timeText, 
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
       System.out.print(time);
}

}
```